# How to determine the font of a QTextBlock

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit, qtextdocument

Let's say a user pastes some random text into a `QTextEdit`. How do you determine which font that text is in. For example, Chinese.

I've tried getting the `QTextCharFormat` for the block. But it seems to be empty of information.
Querying for `fontFamily()` gets me an empty string.

I've also tried to use the `QTextLayout` - but that seems to get me the default layout for the document, not for the specific text block.

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have to go to iterate over the QTextFragment's inside your block. 
The fragments are what contain the specific font information.